# I need to get column names from a table in hibernate

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

```
String[] columnNames = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Java.class).getPropertyNames();

Type[] columnTypes = sessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Java.class).getPropertyTypes();
```

i try this code ...

Comment: What the above code gives you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] columnNames = getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Employee.class).getPropertyNames();

  org.hibernate.type.Type[] columnTypes = getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Employee.class).getPropertyTypes();
```

Try this code Employee.class means this is model class name